# How to truncate button text while it is between spans and all is inside parent span?

Tags: html, css

I've got `span` inside parent `div`, which inside has structure in order: `span, button, span`.

My goal is that `span` fits parent `div`, keep in the same line (does not wrap), truncate text inside span and button and not change the html structure.

Below is code snippet, in which the `span` with its content fits the parent `div` width. The problem is with button text, which does not truncate. When the width is not enough, the button  just dissapears. Nevertheless, when it stands alone, it truncates as it should.

[image]

```css
.box {
  border: 3px solid red;
  outline: 3px solid rosybrown;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.inside-box {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-2 {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h3 class="header">Content Header Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">Click me click me click me click me click me!</button>
  </div>

  <span class="inside-box">
  <span>Before Text</span>
  <button class="btn-2">Click me!</button>
  <span>After Text</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

[Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cnwd2e?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you just want all the nested elements (`span`, `button`) to each ellipsis on overflow? See example below. Also, cheers for actually putting your example in the snippet editor and even providing a stackblitz!

```css
.box {
  border: 3px solid red;
  outline: 3px solid rosybrown;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.inside-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;  
}

.inside-box * {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-2 {
  margin: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h3 class="header">Content Header Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn">Click me click me click me click me click me!</button>
  </div>

  <span class="inside-box">
  <span>Before Text</span>
  <button class="btn-2">Click me!</button>
  <span>After Text</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what I needed. In real case it is a row inside table, where everything must be in one line and if content does not fit the width of the column, it has to ellipsis all the content. Thank you very much!

Comment: However, is it possible to achieve that these elements will ellipsis one by one with css only, not all at the same moment? So, first  'After text' got ellipsis till the end, afterwards the button next and finally the 'Before text' ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @zrowork not sure what you're asking exactly. Are you saying like just the last span would have ellipsis? Or you want the first one to just always take up as much space as possible before the other two elements ellipsis? Maybe help visualizing what you're after would help so long as it doesn't turn into [a chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499670/how-to-truncate-shrink-spans-with-button-bettwen-them-one-by-one-not-all-at-onc   - question. To avoid chameleon question