# How to truncate/shrink spans with button bettwen them one by one, not all at once?

Tags: html, css, sass

There is an issue, in which it is needed to shrink elements inside span one by one. So, according to the image, first fully shrinks `span - AfterText`, while `span - BeforeText` and `button - Click me!` are fully visible. When the `span-AfterText` got fully ellipsis, the `button - Click me!` starts to ellipsis (its text) and the `span - BeforeText` still is fully visible. When `button - Click me!` is fully ellipsed, the `span - BeforeText` starts to ellipsis.

How to achieve that goal? Is it possible only with css? The problem is not with case, where I would have only spans. The problem is due to button, which is kept between spans and does not behave (ellipsis/shrink) like spans. Button will just dissapear, when it does not have enough room to be fully visible.

The image below in the first line represents what I have. Second line shows what is needed.

[image]

```css
.project {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* first box */

.box {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  outline: 3px solid rosybrown;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
}

.box__header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.box__btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.box__inside-box {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box__inside-box * {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box__btn-2 {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}

/* second box */
.box2 {
  border: 3px solid red;
  outline: 3px solid rosybrown;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 220px;
}

.box2__header {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.box2__btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.box2__inside-box {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box2__inside-box * {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box2__btn-2 {
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <!-- first case -->
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h2 class="box__header">Ellipsis all at once</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="box__btn">Click me click me click me click me click me!</button>
    </div>

    <span class="box__inside-box">
<span>BeforeText</span>
    <button class="box__btn-2">Click me!</button>
    <span>AfterText</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <!-- second case -->
  <div class="box2">
    <div>
      <h2 class="box2__header">Ellipsis one by one</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="box2__btn">Click me click me click me click me click me!</button>
    </div>

    <span class="box2__inside-box">
  <span>BeforeText</span>
    <button class="box2__btn-2">Click me!</button>
    <span>AfterText</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-shsp5s?file=src/app/app.component.html)

The real case of this issue is inside table, when the column got shrink and row has text before and after button.

Comment: By strink did u mean the smaller screen size?

Comment: @Amalnandan Nope. By shrinking I mean that I change `width` of  class `box` to smaller, inside which is the rest of content.

Comment: U only need the answer for Ellipsis one by one ? other one is just for reference?
And How do u intent to reduce the width?(by adding class on click?)

Comment: @Amalnandan Yes, I only need answer for Ellipsis one by one. The other is just reference and example what I have already implemented. In given example I change width by changing the value of width in `box` and `box2` class in css file. In real app this width is being handle by resizer written in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to wrap all elements inside `flex` container:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

The key thing is to operate on flex properties like `flex-shrink, flex-grow and flex-basis`. First we need to truncate `button` and `AfterText`. Firtly, we put these elements again inside `.flex-container`. Then, the `AfterText` gets class:

```
.first-to-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

and the `button` on the other hand gets class:

```
.second-to-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

After `AfterText` and `button` ellipsis shrink till it's done, it comes time for `BeforeText` to shrink. Firtly, we have to treat `BeforeText` and container with `AfterText + button` as two elements. So, `AfterText + button` gets class `first-to-shrink` and `BeforeText` gets class `.second-to-shrink`.

Moreover, each element needs these properties to truncate (ellipsis):

```
.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Inside the class `first-to-shrink` is `min-width: 0`. It is necessary to allow truncation inside flexbox. The deep explanation of this feature is on [cssTricks](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/).

Here's [a link to a solution on stackblitz](https://www.example.com/).

```css
.box {
  max-width: 210px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.first-to-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

.second-to-shrink {
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
    <span class="flex-container">
  <span class="second-to-shrink truncate">BeforeText</span>

    <span class="first-to-shrink flex-container">
  <button class="second-to-shrink truncate m-5">Click me!</button>
  <span class="first-to-shrink truncate">AfterText</span>
    </span>

    </span>
  </div>
```